Are Shimano chainring/crankset protectors easily removable?
Are Shimano crankset/chainring guards/protectors easily removable? In other words are they fastened with some screws/bolts or are they riveted? I am most interested in the Acera(M361) cranksets or perhaps the M311.

They are removable.
I find that the guard comes in handy sometimes.
Diagram for the M361

Diagram for the FC-311


I should have checked with shimano myself, didn't think of it. Thanks.

From what I've seen, it seems that bolts/screw is the rule (MT210, old Deore, CUES). Based on the pictures, it seems to also be the case of the M361 - you can guess the position of the screws on pictures.
The only cases I've seen where they are not removable was on trekking e-bikes, where they were soldered on the chainring (and not Shimano) - in metal then, not platic.
